# Is it possible automate editing xml file attributes using ansible play books?

Tags: xml, ansible

Is it possible to edit and modify xml file through ansible playbooks? If possible how? I have got multiple attributes to replace manually in an xml file

```
<Products>
    <Product productId="MetadataServer"> {{ some_value }} <product/>
    <Product productId="DataQualityExceptionConsole" version="11.5.0.1"/> 
</Products>
```

I want to replace `{{ some_value }}` with different value.

Comment: Create template for that xml file and create variable list based on different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize the `replace` module in ansible :

```
- name: Replace Module
  replace: dest=<file-path-name>  regexp='some_value' replace='{{ some_value }}' backup=no
```

Edit your file if possible like below it would be easier to replace :

```
<Products>
    <Product productId="MetadataServer">some_value<product/>
    <Product productId="DataQualityExceptionConsole" version="11.5.0.1"/> 
</Products>
```

Comment: I have different values to replace in one xml file so do I need to have multiple tasks for each?

Comment: @Samson You can write the same above line with different regex and different value in same file.

Answer (score 1):

Create template for that xml file and create key-value list based on different scenarios. When you will execute playbook, ansible will replace all variables in template using variable key and corresponding value.

for e.g.

you want to install tomcat on dev and qa environment. for Dev , you are using port 8080 and for QA environment, you are using port 8081.
you can create template of server.xml with port_no as variable. ( small snippet  can be as below). you can add as many variable as you want.

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="{{ port_no }}" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

2. Once you created template, create key-value list for those variable in you inventory file based on dev & QA environment or in group vars or if you are writing ansible role, you can put these key-value in "defaults" or "vars" folder. There are no of ways to declare variable in ansible. Check this : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Ansible 2.4 you can use the `xml` module or for windows `win_xml` (Ansible 2.7).

See the documentation for the modules: [xml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html) or [win_xml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_xml_module.html)